# Finding the closest pair using Divide and Conquer

Tags: closest-points

I am currently assigned to create a c++ program to find the closest pair of points in a (x,y) coordinate system. However, I am having a lot of trouble trying to understand one thing.

Every tutorial/guide that I have read about the closest pair problem it tells me to sort the set of points by there Y coordinates, but I don't see what the point of this is? Can someone explain to me why we sort it by Y coordinates and what is the use of it? I understand that we sort the points by X in order to get L and X*, but I just don't understand why we have to sort the points by Y coordinates as well.

Comment: You're only able to perform the recombination step of the recursion in constant time if the points are sorted; this reduction is what's responsible for the reduction of the runtime to O(nlogn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't, but then your running time is not improved over O(n<sup>2</sup>). The whole point is to compute as little as possible -- by examining as few points as possible, ignoring those you know will not be part of the answer. Do that by sorting Y.

Here's a pretty good explanation I just googled: http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~cs251/ClosestPair/ClosestPairDQ.html